# How to use GLUT with libdispatch?

Tags: macos, opengl, glut, libdispatch

Both GLUT and libdispatch have their own event-handling loops, which are invoked with functions that never return:  `glutMainLoop();` and `dispatch_main();`, respectively.

I've tried:

```
dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(q, ^{
    glutMainLoop();
});

dispatch_main();
```

...and the window displays, but does not respond to any events or redraw after the initial call to the function specified with `glutDisplayFunc()`.

How can I get GLUT and libdispatch to play nicely together?

Comment: wow. `glut` is still in use? I am getting a nostalgic feeling... Is this for a cross-platform project?

Comment: I'm just looking for a simple way to bring up a window into which to render OpenGL, using C only (no Objective-C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Both of them want to own the message processing loop. And since there's only one such loop, they can't both own it.

If you used [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/), you could find a way to make that work. But a better alternative would be to just use [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/).

Comment: Thanks.  GLFW indeed looks like a better option.

Comment: GLFW isn't working with libdispatch either — see followup on http://stackoverflow.com/q/12570394/64860.